# apigee: where do I correlate the keys with this policy

Tags: api-key, apigee

So I read [this](http://apigee.com/docs/gateway-services/content/api-keys)  in the apigee documentation to understand how I can enforce an API validation policy . I am still confused on where this is correlating the keys with .

1) lets say I have an api key called `key1`  for a client . the

```
<VerifyAPIKey name="APIKeyValidation">
  <APIKey>request.queryparameter.apikey</APIKey>
</VerifyAPIKey>
```

strips the api key from the request . Now my question here is how I should be correlating this `key` with `key1` . any pointers / help with this is greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly 'correlate' the API key. The policy actually validates the key for you. (In fact, sometimes you'll want to strip the API key using another policy--AssignMessage--after the key has been validated.)

The variable in the policy, 'request.queryparameter.apikey', just tells the API proxy where to look for the API key in the request message. Once it has located the key, it does the validation, and throws an exception if the key is not valid.

You can check out this sample for more:

https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/tree/master/sample-proxies/apikey

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . Now my question is , is this policy validating the api key with the key that I get while provisioning a key for an application using a url { https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{myorg}/developers/{developer_email}/apps/{app_name} } ? . Is all this information stored as a map . Also how can I map policies to get values ( for correlation) from maps ?

Comment: Yes. When you register an app, an API key is generated for it. ('Consumer key' is the term used in Apigee Edge.) That is the key that gets validated at runtime. The keys are stored in dedicated database--they're not available as key/value maps.

Comment: If you need to get attributes associated with an API key, you can use the [AccessEntity policy type](http://apigee.com/docs/api-platform/content/retrieve-entity-profiles-using-accessentity). Also, when an API key is validated, a set of variables are populated. They contain attributes of the key. You can refer to the list of variables in the [VerifyAPIKey policy reference](http://apigee.com/docs/gateway-services/content/enforce-access-control-using-verifyapikey).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation . i guess my question essentially becomes , lets say I have an entry in a map I create . How do I create a policy to correlate a param variable that comes in the client request with an entry in the map and if they do not correlate raising an error fault . I know in apigee 3.8 there was a studio where I could modify the connection parameters to make this but I am truly confused on how I could do this in the edge version

Answer (score 0):

Key validation in Apigee Edge is an integrated part of the platform, in the prior generation the key validation was done through an API.

The way it works follows this general flow

1. Key is Generated ( this can be done through a development portal or directly through the Enterprise UI)
2. Key is passed to API with a VerifyAPIKey policy
3. The VerifyAPIKey policy is configured to consume the key from part of the request, this can be a form param, header or query param.

   <VerifyAPIKey name="APIKeyValidation">
     **<APIKey>request.queryparameter.apikey</APIKey>**
   </VerifyAPIKey>
4. The Policy Validates that the API key referenced is valid, if it is valid the policy will fill several variables that are useful for further processing.
5. If the key is invalid the policy will return an appropriate error.
6. If some of the data that is returned from the policy does not match some of your workflow assumptions you can use the raisefault policy with a condition matching your assumption

Here are some documentation pages that talk about these policies and how they work
http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/enforce-access-control-using-verifyapikey
http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/exception-handling-raisefault